# PHP MySql doesnt retrieve data correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve a table from MySql database, but my code returns incorrect data. here is my code below

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "net_trade";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>";

echo "<h1>NET TRADE</h1>";
echo "<div align='center'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a class='nav' href='inventory.php'>INVENTORY</a></li>";
echo "<li><a class='nav' href='supplier.php'>SUPPLIER</a></li>";
echo "<li><a class='nav' href='customer.php'>CUSTOMER</a></li>";
echo "<li><a class='nav' href='sales.php'>SALES</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<form method='POST' action='create_supplier.html'>
      <input type='SUBMIT' class='style19' name='new_item' value='Add New Item'></form>";



echo "<table class='TFtable'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Brand</th>";
echo "<th>Model</th>";
echo "<th>Serial</th>";
echo "<th>Date Supplied</th>";
echo "<th>Supplier</th>";
echo "</tr>";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM inventory");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['0']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['1']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['0'].">".$row['2']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['4']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['5']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['6']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['7']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
mysqli_free_result($result);
}else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "</table>";



?>
```

the result should be this...

[image]

but my code returns something like this..

[image]

the result skips a row from the database table.. thats my main prob

Comment: Props for using mysqli instead of mysql! But why are you echoing out everything? You do know you can just do `?> your html <?php`, right?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the bracketed numbers, `['0']` should be `[0]` Don't free the result until you exit the `if` condition.

Comment: What's the difference between what you're returning and what you want? I can't see any significant differences.

Comment: I suggest you use named columns instead of numbered, e.g. `$row['id']` instead of `$row[0]`. This is especially important when you use `SELECT *`, because you can't tell what order the columns will be.

Comment: the result skips a row from the database table.. thats my main prob.. sorry

Comment: Weird. Your display actually takes the first two columns from the first row, and the rest of your columns from the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this line is goofed up in your code.

```
  echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['0'].">".$row['2']."</a></td>";
```

You need, noticing the matched double quotes in the href, something this this.

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=12345">asd</a></td>
```

What you're getting, I think, is this.

```
  <td><a href='edit.php?id=12345>asd</a></td>
```

Notice your href is started with a single quote (which web browsers tolerate, but is non standard), and isn't ended.

You probably want code looking something like this. String concatenation is not easy to read, so `sprintf()` can be superior for making up this kind of link tag.

```
 echo sprintf ('<td><a href="edit.php?id=%d>%s</a></td>', $row[0], $row[2]);
```

Pro tip: Always do view source when your results are bizarre.

Comment: Thanks! it did the trick haha.. ill be sure to take your tip! thanks again :)